# WebSphere breaks connection while servlet continues to work

Tags: internet-explorer, websphere, keepalive

We have an application running on WebSphere. Requests are often running for a long time (tens of minutes). Our users report that Internet Explorer breaks connection and shows blank screen after some time of waiting. The application log says that requests are finished normally at the servlet level, though it gives a number of errors like this:

> [4/24/15 11:31:19:253 MSK] 0000001f ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W:
>   Thread "WebContainer : 2" (00000027) has been active for 750529
>   milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in
>   the server that may be hung

What are configuration options of WebSphere or Internet Explorer, that should be considered while resolving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd like to point out that if your app is running very long transactions, you need to find an asynchronous way to deal with it.

If you are not responsible for the application design, you can do two (really dirty) things:

- Modify the allert  for hung thread (This is dirty because this may impact every thread in your container and you may miss an alert you needed). [Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21448581) is the way to do so.
- Increase your connexion timeout in the custom properties of your web container (this is dirty because it will impact your performance  and some other configuration as you may be forced to increase you threadpool and after that your memory and so one).

But you should definitely fix what's wrong with your back end AND/OR your implementation (or make a core dump for your developer).